# Difference in Selection Order ORACLE and SQL Server without ORDER clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, migration

I had a requirement where we are migrating our project from ORACLE to SQL Server.

The selection order is differing from ORACLE to SQL Server.

Can some one suggest me to get the same selection order without using ORDER clause.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean the order of records in the table are different?

Comment: Without an explicit `ORDER BY` - there **is no implicit ordering** in any RDBMS. If you need an order - you need to **specify it** explicitly

Comment: by default there are fetching the records without any order, sql is fetching in someway and oracle is fetching in some other way

Answer (score 3):

By definition, `SELECT` without `ORDER BY` is not deterministic, and implementation dependent. Server can decide to deliver your results in any order it thinks more performant.

For example, if you delete some rows and later insert another set of rows, server may reuse that hole to put new data, and this data may be later delivered by SELECT in physical order on disk, not in order of insertion.

Answer (score 2):

You should never rely on the default ordering. If you want results in specific order, you should explicitly use ORDER BY Clause

Answer (score 0):

Without specifying `order by` the records of the table will be displayed based on the server preference and entered order(not if deleted and reinserted)

All `Oracle`, `SQL Server` works on this same policy.